# Ocaml "longest match" rule : "minus" operator parsed as binary or unary

Tags: parsing, ocaml

The function I have:

```
let increment n = n+1;;
```

My call to the function:

```
let x = increment -5;;
```

The error I get:

```
let x = increment -5;;
        ^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type int -> int
       but an expression was expected of type int`
```

Why doesn't `x = -4` after the function call?

I tried finding the answer myself and I ended up here:
http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/lex.html#prefix-symbol

The term "longest match rule" is used in the section Ambiguities, I assume that a clarification of that term would solve my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is easy, `-` is considered here as the binary operator `minus` so OCaml is reading it as `increment minus 5` (`increment` and `5` are the two operands) when what you'd want is `increment the number (minus 5)` (`increment` being a function).

Just write `increment (-5)` and the job's done.

Comment: or use `~-5` the unary negation operator for ints

Comment: But *why* is it considered a binary operator here and not part of the token `-5`? According to the lexical rules linked in the OP, I see no reason why `-` should be seen as its own token here.

Comment: Your _longest match rule_ applies when you can have multiple tokens. Here, `-5` is not a token, hence this error.

Comment: You can write `-5` if there's no ambiguity, for example in `let x = -5` but in case of ambiguity it will always be parsed as the infix binary operator.

Comment: @Lhooq The lexical rule for numbers includes an optional leading "-". So `-5` should be lexed as a single integer token, whereas `- 5` should be lexed as two tokens. But that's clearly not what happens, so, unless you can point out what I missed on the linked page, it seems to me that the rules on the page are not accurate (or the compiler does not implement them correctly, depending on your point of view).

Comment: Well, _should_ is a strong statement. What would you say to those who write `for i = 0 to length-1` ? Are they supposed to put a space before `1` ? I suggest you read http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html, the 6.7.4 part about operators.

Comment: @Lhooq No, of course not, because `-` can't appear in identfiiers. What does that question have to do with my point?

Comment: @Lhooq as mentioned by sepp2k, http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html#integer-literal makes it very clear that `-5` is in itself a valid integer-literal token. The lexer thinks otherwise (https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/parsing/lexer.mll#L293). There might be very good reason to consider only positive numbers as a token, but the real issue is the discrepancy between the manual and the implementation.

Comment: @Virgile The reason, I assume, is that it's confusing if `x-1` and `x - 1` acted differently (which would be the case if the lexer were implemented as described in the manual because according to that, the former should be lexed as `LIDENT("x"), INT("-1", None)` and the latter as `LIDENT("x"), MINUS, INT("1", None)`). In fact it is my understanding that signs are generally not part of the lexical rules for numbers for exactly that reason. So I was surprised that the manual included it. That seems to simply have been an error in the manual though.

Comment: Well, we could argue about the manual but the inconsistency is in the fact that they didn't said that the `-` is parsed (because you can't just look at the lexer to get the syntax, in this case it's not one token but two so you should look at the parser) as the unary minus operator when there's no ambiguity (_i.e._, `-` is not in an infix position).

Comment: Right, you can't tell how things are parsed from the lexing rules. But you can tell how they are lexed. You say "it's not one token, but two", but how do you justify that from the manual? The manual says that integer tokens can start with a "-", so if that were true, `-1` would clearly be one token. Once we decide that `-1` is two tokens, the rest is obvious from the parser, but the decision whether `-1` is one or two tokens is made by the lexer. And the manual's description of the lexing rules gives a different answer to that question than the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using parentheses, as suggested in the other answer, is to use the `@@` application operator, e.g.:

```
let increment n = n + 1
let x = increment @@ -5
```

Briefly, `f @@ x` is the same as `f x`, but the `@@` operator has lower precdence than arithmetic operations, while function application has higher precedence. Thus, using the application operator allows you to omit parentheses.

Sometimes, the reverse application operator `|>` can be more idiomatic; it is typically used to "pipe" an expression through one or more function applications.

Example:

```
let increment n = n + 1
let x = -5 |> increment
let clamp x low high = x |> min high |> max low
```